# How to scale up the parameters of a trigonometric function

Tags: functions, trigonometry

### Short version

Given a function with parameters $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$,and $e$ that approximates a set of data that has been scaled down to the range $[0, 1]$, how can I compute the parameters $a'$, $b'$, $c'$, $d'$,and $e'$ that approximate the unscaled/raw data?

### Details

I have some raw data that looks like this:

$X_{raw}$: 67 integers from 0 to 66

$Y_{raw}$: 67 positive numbers from 97.2 to 92.1

I haven't done much mathematics in a while, but when plotted, the data looks roughly like a trigonometric function with a downward trend. So as an experiment/learning exercise, I'm trying to approximate the data using a trigonometric function. I've done this by scaling both the $X$ and $Y$ data to the range $[0, 1]$ using the following formulae:

$$
x_{i_{scaled}} = {x_{i_{raw}} - \min(X_{raw})\over \max(X_{raw}) - \min(X_{raw})} = {x_{i_{raw}}\over 66}
$$

$$
y_{i_{scaled}} = {y_{i_{raw}} - \min(Y_{raw})\over \max(Y_{raw}) - \min(X_{raw})} = {y_{i_{raw}} - 92.1\over 97.2 - 92.1}
$$

From there, I have managed to approximate the **scaled** data using the function:

$$
y_{i_{scaled}} = a\cdot \cos\left({2\pi x_{i_{scaled}}\over b} - c\right) + d +ex_{i_{scaled}}
$$

I have identified values for the five parameters $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$,and $e$ (using gradient descent with a mean squared error loss function), however, these values work for the scaled data, so they are not appropriate for modelling the **unscaled** / **raw** data. I'm trying to figure out how to scale them back up to the equivalent $a'$, $b'$, $c'$, $d'$,and $e'$, such that they approximate the raw data. I can't figure out how to do this.

Through experimentation, I've found that I can approximate the **raw** $y$ data as a function of the **scaled** $X$ data, using the optimal parameters I computed through gradient descent:

$$
y_{i_{raw}} = \alpha \cdot \left( a \cdot\cos\left({2\pi x_{i_{scaled}}\over b} - c\right) + d +ex_{i_{scaled}} \right) + \beta
$$

Where

$\alpha = \max (Y_{raw}) - \min (Y_{raw})$

$\beta = \min (Y_{raw})$

But what I'm after is values for $a'$, $b'$, $c'$, $d'$,and $e'$, such that:

$$
y_{i_{raw}} = a'\cdot \cos\left({2\pi x_{i_{raw}}\over b'} - c'\right) + d' + e'x_{i_{raw}}
$$

I'm assuming (through nothing more than intuition) that these values can be obtained from the values $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$,and $e$ somehow, along with some kind of wrangling with the scaling transformations... But I haven't found a way to do it.

### Update

After some more experimentation, I've found a way to scale up the parameter values from $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$,and $e$ to $a'$, $b'$, $c'$, $d'$,and $e'$ in a way that approximates the raw data:

$a' = a \cdot \alpha_y$

$b' = b \cdot \alpha_x + \beta_x$

$c' = c$

$d' = \alpha_y \left(d - e {\beta_x\over \alpha_x}\right) + \beta_y$

$e' = \alpha_y {e \over \alpha_x}$

Where

$\alpha_x = \max (X_{raw}) - \min (X_{raw})$

$\beta_x = \min (X_{raw})$

$\alpha_y = \max (Y_{raw}) - \min (Y_{raw})$

$\beta_y = \min (Y_{raw})$

But I don't fully understand why this works...